# Left join in select query Yii2 - Unknown column 'single' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2, left-join

Why this query is not working?

```
public function actionInsert()
{
    $model = new NotificationsEvents();

    $date_at = (new Query())
        ->select(['single-events.date_at'])
        ->from('single-events')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'user.birthday = single-events.date_at');


    $event_id = (new Query())
        ->select(['single-events.id'])
        ->from('single-events')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = single-events.id');

    (new Query())->createCommand()->insert('notifications_events', [
        'type' => 7,
        'date_at' => $date_at,
        'event_id' => $event_id,
    ])->execute();

}
```

I need to insert user birthday in `notifications_events.date_at`, and user ID in `notifications_events.event_id`, but this code is not working:

> Unknown column 'single' in 'on clause'

Comment: If you really have a table called single-events then you should escape it (or better still change the table name) in your case mysql interprets the dash as minus and sees single as a column name,

Comment: Use Underscore (_) as seperator for table and column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`single-events` is not a valid/safe name for table, because it contains `-`. You should either quote it in every possible place:

```
public function actionInsert() {
    $model = new NotificationsEvents();

    $date_at = (new Query())
        ->select(['{{single-events}}.date_at'])
        ->from('single-events')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'user.birthday = {{single-events}}.date_at');


    $event_id = (new Query())
        ->select(['{{single-events}}.id'])
        ->from('single-events')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = {{single-events}}.id');

    (new Query())->createCommand()->insert('notifications_events', [
        'type' => 7,
        'date_at' => $date_at,
        'event_id' => $event_id,
    ])->execute();
}
```

Or use some more practical name for table, like `single_events`.

Answer (score 0):

Another quoting method:  using backtics:

```
`single-events`
```